# Unable to run flutter app on device with flutter_facebook_auth

Tags: ios, flutter, facebook-login

I am trying to implement login with facebook in my Flutter app. It seems the library to do so is https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth/install .

I followed all the installation instructions - and I am able to correctly run the app in the iPhone simulator. I am unable to run the app on my own device. The XCode build completes successfully, i.e. `flutter build ios` works but `flutter run -d XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` (device ID snipped) fails with a lot of errors, here is some of the output of `flutter run` (see below).

How do I get this to run on my device?

```
/Users/imrigoldberg/Documents/flytrex/shopper/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/Instrument/FBSDKInstrumentManager.m:58:52: error: reference to 'FBSDKSettings' is ambiguous
                                          settings:(id<FBSDKSettings>)settings
                                                       ^
    In file included from /Users/imrigoldberg/Documents/flytrex/shopper/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/Instrument/FBSDKInstrumentManager.m:34:
    In file included from /Users/imrigoldberg/Documents/flytrex/shopper/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/FBSDKSettings+SettingsProtocols.h:22:
    /Users/imrigoldberg/Documents/flytrex/shopper/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/PrivateHeaders/FBSDKSettingsProtocol.h:23:11: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'FBSDKSettings'
    @protocol FBSDKSettings
              ^
    In file included from /Users/imrigoldberg/Documents/flytrex/shopper/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/Instrument/FBSDKInstrumentManager.m:31:
    /Users/imrigoldberg/Documents/flytrex/shopper/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKSettingsProtocol.h:23:11: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'FBSDKSettings'
    @protocol FBSDKSettings
              ^
    /Users/imrigoldberg/Documents/flytrex/shopper/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/Instrument/FBSDKInstrumentManager.m:58:52: error: type argument 'FBSDKSettings' must be a pointer (requires a '*')
                                          settings:(id<FBSDKSettings>)settings
                                                       ^
                                                                     *
    /Users/imrigoldberg/Documents/flytrex/shopper/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/Instrument/FBSDKInstrumentManager.m:58:49: error: type arguments cannot be applied to non-class type 'id'
                                          settings:(id<FBSDKSettings>)settings
                                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2 warnings and 14 errors generated.
```

Comment: Do you have Swift support enabled for your project?